# Authorize in ASP.NET CORE Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have added **[Authorize]** attribute over my **BaseController**. Without JWT token it shows 401 error, I need to customize that 401 error. I need to understand at which place the Application throws 401 error. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to customize this behavior, but I think the most straightforward one is to write a [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

```
// Startup.Configure method

app.UseRouting();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Token Validation Has Failed. Request Access Denied");
    }
});

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints();
```

Comment: Can you suggest me with some blogs or videos to learn and Implement it @Martin